# Advertising Open Source - Community Ads for 2016

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, advertising

It's 2016, and the new 300px-wide sidebar has just rolled out network wide. When that's complete, graduated sites around the network will start to run new community ad cycles.

To be ready for them, let's start designing! Submit as answers on this post an ad that you'd like to see representing Open Source Stack Exchange to the rest of the network.

- Ads must now be **300px wide by 250px tall**, or preferably double for retina
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur (the Stack Exchange image hosting service).
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).
- You **can** resubmit ads from last time round, if you want to see them used again. (Though you'll have to resize them.)
- When an ad reaches 6 votes *here*, feel free to take it and post in on the various community ad submission threads on other (preferably related) sites.

Let's advertise ourselves!

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's the difference between this thread and the old [community promotion ads](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/q/80/327) thread?

Comment: @Mureinik New year. Every year, the ad threads on other sites reset so that there are fresh ads on there. We're doing the same - fresh ads for a fresh ad cycle.

Comment: @Mureinik And also because the sizes are changing :)

Comment: It would be nice to define precisely what is an advertisement? I thought it is related to things that are sold and imply some monetary exchange.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not necessarily; an ad can be about pretty much anything. Community ads in particular are created to promote things that relate to the topic of the site, such as projects or schemes.

Comment: Then that should be *explicitly* stated. It is not at all obvious for me (and AFAIK, it is false in Europe; something *without* monetary compensation won't be called an ad; but I am not a lawyer)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This thread is more specifically for adverts that promote this site to the rest of the SE network, rather than anything else.

Comment: Ok, but in general you should define what is an ad to you (StackExchange). Apparently your definition is not the same as the one I heard (e.g. in Paris Metro, we have "publicités" which are commercial ads). I was quite surprised by your private message mentioning that some of my question (on OpenSource) is an ad.

Comment: Perhaps "promotion" would be a better term? It's not necessarily commercial, but it promotes *something*.

Comment: Whatever word you use,please define it. Bear with the many non-native English speakers like me (and non US citizens)

Comment: What sites should we target?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Anywhere that's related. The ads should preferably be targeted towards the site they'll display on (unless they're really generic).